# Image won't close on click - JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, jsfiddle

I have been working on creating an image that pops up only on mobile screens. At first, I was doing this with a CSS class. I was able to make an image load on the website launch and close while clicking it. However, I wasn't able to make the image show on mobile screens only.

I now have the issue where I am using an HTML id to make the image load on only mobile screens. However, I can't make the image close upon click. I think the error is in my JS code but I am not sure.

Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vd68wa52/)

```
    HTML:
            <img id="yourimage" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/05/02/22/16/apple-blossoms-1368187_960_720.jpg">
            <p>
            Why does the image warp when resizing and why doesn't it close on click?
            </p>


    CSS:
    #yourimage {
      display: none;
        position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      width: 50%;
      height: 50%;
    }

    @media (max-width: 500px) {
      #yourimage {
        display: block;
      }
    }

JS:

function showPopup() {
  document.GetElementId('yourimage').style.display = 'block';
}
showPopup(); // show modal image. 

function closePopUp() {
  document.GetElementId('yourimage').style.display = 'none';
}

document.GetElementId('yourimage').addEventListener('click', closePopUp); // hide modal image
```

I appreciate anyone taking the time to help me and look forward to any responses :)

- J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getElementById` instead of `GetElementId`:

```js
function showPopup() {
  document.getElementById('yourimage').style.display = 'block';
}
showPopup(); // show modal image. 

function closePopUp() {
  document.getElementById('yourimage').style.display = 'none';
}

document.getElementById('yourimage').addEventListener('click', closePopUp); // hide modal image
```

```css
#yourimage {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #yourimage {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="yourimage" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/05/02/22/16/apple-blossoms-1368187_960_720.jpg">

<p>
  Why does the image warp when resizing and why doesn't it close on click?
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you! Embarrassed I didn't realize that. For some reason the image loads even though I have the CSS telling it to only load on certain screen sizes. Do you know why?

Comment: @JosephPandolfi No problem ;) Can you please `validate` and `upvote` my answer?

Comment: Gotcha! Sorry I'm new here. I have no clue why the image loads on all screen sizes when I only want it to load on mobile screens.

Is there a way to make the image fit to the screen that it loads on to?

Comment: @JosephPandolfi No problem ;) I have the answer for that but please open a new question for that and drop me a line so I can answer it

Comment: I have uploaded a new question! I look forward to your response :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61524726/how-to-make-image-load-on-mobile-screens-only-and-be-responsive